# Dropzone js not showing buttons

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I'd appreciate some help with sorting out my dropzone.

I'm trying to setup Dropzone on my site, using the example code given on the dropzone website (http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html). I get an error:

> Invalid Dropzone Element

I can see the three buttons load initially and then they disappear and I get an empty div.

```
            <div class="sixteen columns omega">
            <div class="page">
                <div class="page-inner" id="dropzone">
                    <div class="table table-striped" class="files" id="previews">
                        <div id="template" class="file-row">
                        <!-- This is used as the file preview template -->
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary start">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                                <span>Start</span>
                            </button>
                            <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                                <span>Cancel</span>
                            </button>
                            <button data-dz-remove class="btn btn-danger delete">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                            <span>Delete</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var previewNode = document.querySelector("div#template");
    previewNode.id = "";
    var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
    previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.section, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
        url: "/target-url",
        thumbnailWidth: 80,
        thumbnailHeight: 80,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
        autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
        previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
        clickable: ".fileinput-button" // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    });

    myDropzone.on("addedfile", function (file) {
        // Hookup the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function () { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
    });

    // Update the total progress bar
    myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function (progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
    });

    myDropzone.on("sending", function (file) {
        // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
        // And disable the start button
        file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    });

    // Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function (progress) {
        document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
    });

    // Setup the buttons for all transfers
    // The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
    // `clickable` has already been specified.
    document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function () {
        myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
    };
    document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function () {
        myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
    };
</script>
```